# Multiples of times values add in c#.net?

Tags: c#

I want to add more than two time values in c#.net how? Examples:

129:43:50 + 20:20:00 + 30:00:10 = 180:04:00

Comment: Associativity of addition? _129:43:50 + 20:20:00 + 30:00:10 =  (129:43:50 + 20:20:00) + 30:00:10 = 180:04:00_

Comment: What are each componant? Days, Hours, minutes?

Comment: Need more info.  What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried exactly?  Just covert each one into a DateTime and add the Days, Hours, and Minutes together.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using [`TimeSpan.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx)? This really is an odd question though.

EDIT:

Based on your comment I suggest you take a look at [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) and [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee372287.aspx) on MSDN to see how you can format the `TimeSpan`.

Comment: ya i used Timespan.add only but i got the output 7.12:04:00 i need the output 180:04:00 this format

Comment: +1 for "This really is an odd question though"

Comment: @Karthikeyan Then format the output using `TimeSpan`'s properties: `TotalHours`, `Minutes`, `Seconds`

Comment: @Karthikeyan I've added the answer with the formating.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `List<TimeSpan>` you can use LINQ:

```
List<TimeSpan> times = new List<TimeSpan>();

TimeSpan total = times.Aggregate(new TimeSpan(), (t1, t2) => t1 + t2);
```

Then, for the formating use:

```
string result = string.Format ("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (int)total .TotalHours, total.Minutes, total.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the method

```
public DateTime Add(TimeSpan value)
```

? Its fairly the first result on google.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx) object.  You'll need to construct, then add the values together.